# My question, your website

Tags: discussion, support

*edit: After reading through your meta it is obvious that you have just renamed, so this post is more of a reminder for you to make sure everything else gets updated to stop confusion!*

This is not a complaint, just wanted to point a few things out. First up, see [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/is-it-possible-to-live-solely-off-soup) which was closed as 'off topic' for asking about nutrition.

Secondly, see [this description](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7080/fitness-nutrition) on Area51 for *this site*:

> Beta Q&A site for physical fitness professionals, athletes, trainers,
>   and those providing health-related needs. **Topics include** exercise
>   and training, **nutrition and diets**, wellness, and activities
>   related to strength, endurance, agility, and cardiovascular fitness.

So with your website advertised as for fitness and nutrition, Area51 needs your site definition editing to reflect the change in scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that things can be confusing, but Area51 isn't representative of the site in its current/final form. It just describes the site the way it was launched into Private Beta.

So while I'm sorry you were misled by it, it took us a long time to get the FAQ into its current shape and form. We also have no power to edit the Area51 description, but perhaps the team will consider updating it for us.

Hopefully you have other exercise related questions we can help you with in the future.

Comment: Yeah no worries, I understand these things don't always propagate as planned. :)